# Not able to edit Polygon after editable option as true also in Drawing Manager of Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps

I have tried to draw Polygon using Drawing Manager and send the Polygon Coordinates to PHP script(to store in Database).

> 1)i have coded editable option as 'true' for polygon. But i am not to
>   edit the polygon.I am not to find what i did wrong?
>
> 2)Also i try to get
>
> > Polygon paths using getPaths method..it is returned as array..How do i
> >     check this coordinates are correct. If i put in alert in displays as
> >     'Object[] Object'.Please help me to solve these problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the drawing mode to true (to enable map interactions). the following code will do the trick :)

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

});
```

with regards to the 2nd part im currently working on that now. use console.log instead of alert.

Comment: Can you share me why we need to set the Drawing Mode ?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this. but when the drawing mode isn't set you can't interact with drawings... hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

For the path:

```
var thisPath=polygon.getPath();
for(i=0;i<thisPath.length;i++){
    var latlng=thisPath.getAt(i);
    pathString= pathString+', '+ latlng.lat()+' - '+ latlng.lng()+'\n'
}
alert (pathString);
```

Answer (score 0):

For part 2, sharingStuff code would work, I preferred for the path to be a json object,

```
vertices = this.polygon.getPath();
var points = [];
// Iterate over the vertices.
if(this.polygon.getMap() == null){
    return false;
}
for (var i =0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
    points.push(xy.lat() +"," + xy.lng());
}
return JSON.stringify({points: points});
```

either method is fine, just thought I'd give you another option. :)